# Parameter is not valid when use picturebox control

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Parameter is not valid.
StackTrace:at System.Drawing.Image.get_FrameDimensionsList()   at

```
  System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.CanAnimate(Image image)   at

  System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.ImageInfo..ctor(Image image)   at

  System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(Image image, EventHandler onFrameChangedHandler)   at

  System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate(Boolean animate)   at

  System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate()   at

  System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)   at

  System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)   at

  System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)   at

  System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)   at

  System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)   at

  System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)   at

  System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)   at

  System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
```

Source Error Message:Parameter is not valid.

Comment: `StackTrace` is not enough, you should post your code also.

Comment: I have almost same problem with same call stack (through OnVisibleChanged). Could you gives us more informations on the context? What kind of control are you using?